# Limit what sections get exported/processed in Pandoc markdown?

Tags: pandoc

Is there a way to control/limit what content get processed by Pandoc in a pandoc markdown document?

What I miss is OrgMode's `:noexport:` tag that could be attached to a section header so that
that section would not be exported.

I'm looking for a similar or alternative way to "comment out" sections of pandoc markdown so that they get ignored when I convert the document to pdf in particular.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to modify the document with pandoc's [Lua filters](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html). For example, the `noexport-subtrees.lua` filter available as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/tarleb/a0f41adfa7b0e5a9be441e945f843299) recreates Org's behavior:

> Mark headers with {.noexport} to exclude them from the final document:
>
> ```
> # First
>
> First paragraph.
>
> # This is an internal note {.noexport}
>
> ## with subsections
>
> And words. If only a few.
>
> # Third
>
> ## Yet more
>
> This is more content.
> ```
>
> Running `pandoc --lua-filter=noexport-subtrees.lua test.md` gives
>
> ```html
> <h1 id="first">First</h1>
> <p>First paragraph.</p>
> <h1> id="third">Third</h1>
> <h2 id="yet-more">Yet more</h2>
> <p>This is more content.</p>
> ```